# Testing if a POST api endpoint is working with PHP

Tags: php, api, post, endpoint

I have a ticketing system and I just enabled an API endpoint that points to a custom PHP file I created. Everytime I update a ticket it sends the data to this endpoint saying its updated. How do I test if it actually  is sending any data? Supposedly its doing a POST to that php file. I was thinking of sending this POST data to a a plain text file in the same folder to test.

But is there a better way to do this to test what that end point is sending?

Comment: Logging is a pretty normal way to monitor such things yes. You can log on the client side (sender) and on the server side (receiver) if you want. And if you're really paranoid you could even monitor the network traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try checking the network tab in chrome dev tools. There you can look up under "doc" or "XHR" which post headers have been sent.

Comment: That's assuming the request is coming from a browser...there's no specific mention of that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log your inputs, outputs, or anything you want. There is a good log library you can use that name is [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) but you can use the buffer or write in output using `var_dump` or write directly in a log file.

Also, you can use the [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) to debug your codes